# how to count check checkboxes in a specific div JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to alert the amount of check boxes that are checked in a specific div (not the ones in the `<head>`!), here is the code :

HTML

```
<div class="changer">

<label><input id="mode" type="checkbox" name="mode" value="Mode"        onclick="mode()" />Mode</label><br />

<label><input id="map" type="checkbox" name="map" value="Map" onclick="map()"/>Map</label><br />

<label><input id="joueurs" type="checkbox" name="joueurs" value="Joueurs" onclick="joueurs()" />Joueurs</label><br />

<label><input id="points" type="checkbox" name="points" value="Points" onclick="points()" />Points</label><br />

</div>



</head>

<body>

<div id="text">

</div>

</body>

<button id="send" onclick="send()">Envoyer</button>
```

Javascript

```
function joueurs() {
    if((document.getElementById("joueurs").checked == true)) {

            joueursall.style.display = 'inline';
            text.style.display = 'inline';
    }

            else {
                if((document.getElementById("mode").checked == true)) {
                    modeall.style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('mode').checked = false;
                }
                joueursall.style.display = 'none';
                text.style.display = 'none';

            }

        }


document.getElementById("playerlist").addEventListener("change", function() {

var selected = this.value;
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < selected; i++) {
html += '<div class="grpjoueur"> <span class="sub-text">Player</span> <label><input type="checkbox" name="botbot" value="BOT"/>BOT</label </div>';
}
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html;
});
```

Here is the Javascript, it adds 'Joueurs' Dropdownlist if Joueurs is checked and then pop X times something, including a check box, according to the number selected in the Dropdownlist in the #text div

I tried multiple things but always return 0 or all the checkboxes...

Comment: `$("#text :checked").length`

Comment: 1. In head goes page meta (the info for the browser). All the code that has to be displayed for the user should be in body.
2. In your example you have no checkboxes in #text div. It's normal to get zero results.

Comment: @RaduNemerenco Forgot my javascript part, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla JS you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to query the checkboxes, and then `.length` to get the number of checkboxes.

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
alert(checkboxes.length);
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/8577b601c3193486437d86ae3c853399/)

If you want to alert only the length of the checked checkboxes, you can query them like this:

```
var checkedInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");
alert(checkedInputs.length);
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/bb71d2b69575cb2b2e1ba9f3fa65f276)

- when you click on the button, it will alert the number of checked boxes

Comment: Forgot my javascript part, please take a look